# Dynamic concatenation by header names, lost on how to do this

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

I need to a dynamic way to concatinate some cells in a row with a delimiter (in this instance `|`) as the columns move about (per project) this has to be by header names (there might be from 2 to many) columns that need to be concatinated for a project

I am trying to use arrays as there can be as many as 4000,000 rows

I have been trying for hours and here is my effort I know it is `very wrong` but I am at a loss

Thank you

```
Sub CAT()

fCAT "ElementsFile", "ElementsFile", "D", Array("Age", "Gender Identity", "Ethnicity1", "Ethnicity1")

End Sub

Sub fCAT(sShtName As String, pbShtName As String, InsertCol As String, ar As Variant)
Dim myresult
Dim col1 As String, col2 As String, col3 As String, col4 As String
Dim aLR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

'Totaly at a loss here
For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
   Dim ari As Variant
   Dim coli As String
Next i

 Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sShtName)
Set wsPB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(pbShtName)

With wsS
     aLR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
       j = .Rows(1).Find(ar(i)).Column
      ari = .Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(aLR, j)).Select
 Next i
End With

 'Totaly at a loss here
 ReDim myresult(1 To aLR, 1 To aLR)
   For k = 1 To aLR
     For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
      j = wsS.Rows(1).Find(ar(i)).Column
         myresult(k, 1) = Cells(k, j) & "|" & Cells(k, j + 1) & "|" & Cells(k, j + 2) & "|" & Cells(k, j + 3)
  Next i
Next k

wsT.Range("D1").Resize(aLR, 1) = myresult

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem? What isn't working? What's the expected outcome vs the actual outcome? Read this http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally came up with a bit of a mess maybe but it works

```
Sub concat()
Dim myresult, CN
Dim HN As Variant
Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsPB As Worksheet
Dim str As String
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

HN = Array("Age", "Gender Identity", "Ethnicity1", "Ethnicity2")

 Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ElementsFile")
Set wsPB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ElementsFile")

wsPB.Columns(4).Insert

ReDim CN(0 To UBound(HN))
With wsS
      LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Get Array of column numbers coresponding to Header names
    For i = 0 To UBound(HN)
         j = wsS.Rows(1).Find(HN(i)).Column
         CN(i) = j
    Next i
End With
ReDim myresult(1 To LR, 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To LR
str = vbNullString
   If Not (IsEmpty(Cells(i, CN(0))) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, CN(1)))) Then
      For k = UBound(HN) To 0 Step -1
         If k <> UBound(HN) Then
            str = Cells(i, CN(k)) & "|" & str
         Else: str = Cells(i, CN(k)) & str
         End If
      Next k
        myresult(i, 1) = str

      Else
      myresult(i, 1) = vbNullString
   End If
Next i
str = vbNullString
wsPB.Range("D1").Resize(LR, 1) = myresult

End Sub
```